# C# VSTO Excel can't use en-US list separators in code

Tags: c#, excel, com, vsto, excel-interop

I am creating a VSTO AddIn in C# using Interop to communicate with Excel. I've been reading this article regarding different locales in Excel:

https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/visualstudio/vsto/globalization-and-localization-of-excel-solutions

The article says:

> By default, Office solutions that you create by using Visual Studio
>   are not affected by the end user's locale settings, and always behave
>   as though the locale is English (United States). For example, if you
>   get or set the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.Value2* property
>   in Excel, the data must be formatted the way that locale ID 1033
>   expects. If you use a different data format, you might get unexpected
>   results.

My current locale is set to German which uses `;` for list separators, instead of `,` that en-US does.

This is the code that works on my machine:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void ButtonClick(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    var range = Worksheet.Range["A1:B1;C1:D1;E1:F1"];
}
```

This doesn't work and throws generic `HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` exception:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void ButtonClick(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    var range = Worksheet.Range["A1:B1,C1:D1,E1:F1"];
}
```

So what is it? How do I know which locale to use in my code? I thought I was safe by always using en-US.

Comment: `"A1:B1,C1:D1,E1:F1"` is correct for `Range` and should work on all locales (and does when called from VBA). The problem must be specific to VSTO.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 0):

The text you quote is referring to information that's sent to Excel (written to a cell, for example). What you're doing is a bit of a grey area: you're using list separators in an array definition.

Compare your use of `Range` with this assignation of a formula to a cell (Range):

```
string quote = '"'.ToString();
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet.Range["F3"].Formula =
    "=IF(A1=1," + quote + "yes" + quote + "," + quote + "no" + quote + ")";
```

A comma is used as the *argument separator* in the formula, which is correct for the en-us locale, as per the documentation. This is being written into Excel. In the German locale, this appears in the workbook as `=IF(A1=1;"yes";"no")`, with semicolons - VSTO takes care of making sure the result is correct *in the workbook". This is the kind of thing that's meant in the documentation.

For the problem you're encountering, you have to pass the correct list separator for the current locale ("culture") where the code is running, which you can do like this:

```
string rangeDesignation = "A1:B1,C1:D1,E1:F1";
string listSeparator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;
if (listSeparator != ",")
{
    rangeDesignation = rangeDesignation.Replace(",", listSeparator);
}
Excel.Range range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet.Range[rangeDesignation];
```

Comment: `Formula` is supposed to always use en-us, whereas [`FormulaLocal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.formulalocal?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Range_FormulaLocal) is supposed to always use the interface language. It is not VSTO that "makes sure the result is correct in the workbook", it's the fact that Excel internally works in en-us and R1C1 reference style, but may *display* formulas in a different language and/or a different reference style.

Comment: I used `Formula` just as a convenient comparison for the use of commas vs. semicolons in the VSTO code and what is meant by that documentation. If you have a better example I'll be happy to incorporate it.